# Tags on volumes created with EC2 instances in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating my *AWS CloudFormation* stacks with tags.

When I do this, all *EC2* instances created by the stacks also get the tags (which is what I want). But all volumes attached to those *EC2* instances don't get the tags.

Can I somehow change this? I want tags on all resources that support them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags are applied non-transitively; you'll have to explicitly associate tags with each resource. Quoting from [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-tags) for `AWS::EC2::Instance` resource type, tags are:

> An arbitrary set of tags (key–value pairs) for this instance.

If you really want to associate tags to volumes using *AWS CloudFormation*, the alternate way would be to create volumes (and specify tags for volumes) using `AWS::EC2::Volume` and attach them to EC2 instances using `AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment`. Another alternate would be to accomplish this using [Lambda-backed custom resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html?shortFooter=true).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Instances created via Terraform (50-75 instances). I wrote this Powershell + AWS CLI script to tag the volumes:

```
$instances = aws ec2 --profile=xxxxxx-us-east-2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId]" --output text

foreach ($instance in $instances)
{
    Write-Host $instance


    $filter = "Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$instance"
    $volumes = aws ec2 --profile=xxxxxx-us-east-2 describe-volumes --filters $filter --query "Volumes[].Attachments[].[VolumeId]"  --output text
    Write-Host $volumes

    $raw= aws ec2 --profile=xxxxxx-us-east-2 describe-instances --instance-ids $instance --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags]" --output json
    $temp1 = $raw | ConvertFrom-Json 
    $temp2 = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject  $temp1.GetValue(0).GetValue(0).GetValue(0)
    $tags = $temp2 | ConvertFrom-Json 
 
    foreach ($volume in $volumes)
    {
        Write-Host $volume

        foreach($tag in $tags)
        {
            Write-Host $tag.Key'='$tag.Value
            $parm = "Key=" + $tag.Key + ",Value=" + $tag.Value
            aws ec2 --profile=xxxxxx-us-east-2 create-tags --resources $volume --tags $parm

        }

    }
}
```